# Unable to create Appflow CDK using Python in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

, I am trying to deploy an Appflow CDK and get the following error:

Stack Deployments Failed: Error: The stack named cdk-l-appflow-12202022 failed to deploy: UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE: Resource handler returned message: "Unable to retrieve secrets for secret Id : arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:588799296974:secret:vipsfsecret-66dxxqk0BGck-sPRzQs due to access denied. Please ensure that AppFlow has access on secrets manager resource and KMS key used for encryption. (Service: Appflow, Status Code: 403, Request ID: 9aa02dee-db8c-46db-b495-8cb1392f510e)" (RequestToken: 47e0f482-6cd5-c7e6-1121-e107963c82e6, HandlerErrorCode: GeneralServiceException)

The appflow authentication secrets are in Secrets Manager. I have perimissioned it as such:
{
"Version" : "2012-10-17",
"Statement" : [ {
"Effect" : "Allow",
"Principal" : {
"Service" : "secretsmanager.amazonaws.com"
},
"Action" : [ "secretsmanager:GetResourcePolicy", "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue", "secretsmanager:DescribeSecret", "secretsmanager:ListSecretVersionIds", "secretsmanager:ListSecrets" ],
"Resource" : "*"
} ]
}

Does anyone have thoughts/suggestions please?

Tried creating a new KMS and provided Key policy at teamrole level. So permissions including kms:decrypt are given.